# Read_HTML skiprows some rows not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, html-table

I'm trying to scrape from a website a table in which my header is in row 1, and I need to skip rows 0 and 2. I try the following

```
tables=pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'),header=0,skiprows=[0,2])
```

What this is doing is skip rows 0,1 and 2, and then gets the header of the row four. Understandind the problem is in skiprows, I've tried the following:

```
skiprows=[[0],[2]] error list not hashable
header=0,skiprows=(0,2) here gets header of row 1, but skips rows 0,2 and 3 (why 3?)
skiprows=0,2 error because it is giving too many arguments
```

In short, I need to put header row 1, and skip rows 0 and 2 and I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end this is the right answer

```
tables=pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'),header=0,skiprows=(0,2))
```

What was happening was that after that, I didnt' erase my previous method to drop that extra column, which was

```
tables[0].drop(tables[0].head(1).index,inplace=True)
```

and that made the table drop not only row 2, but afterwards row 3 as well.